# ¿Cómo verificar si 2 elementos consecutivos de un array son iguales en python?

Tags: python, array

Me encontré con un inconveniente con la tarea de poder verificar si 2 elementos ingresados por teclado en un array son repetidos, este es el codigo:

```
n=3
for i in range(n):
    os.system("color 0f")
    print("Valores ingresados:",i,"de",n)
    A=[input("Valores: ")]
    if i!=0: #Si i=0 entonces no se compara con ningún valor ya que es el primer valor
        if A[i-1]==A[i]: #se compara la posición actual con la posición anterior
            print("Se ingresaron 2 números consecutivos repetidos, ingrese nuevamente valores distintos")
```

Sin embargo, me esta dando error:

```
if A[i-1]==A[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Si el array es zero-based (arranca en cero), entonces la posición i va a estar por fuera del array cuando i == n, siempre.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en cada vuelta estas sobrescribiendo la lista `A`, básicamente siempre tendrás una posición porque estas en el `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma fácil de saber si dos elementos consecutivos en un iterable es, primero usando [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) el cual crea una lista de tuplas de dos listas.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7]
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7)]
```

Usando ahora comprension para comparar los elementos en cada tupa y finalmente [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any) devuelve `True` si cualquier elemento de un iterable es `True`.

```
>>> list(i == j for i, j in zip(a, b))
[False, False, False]
>>> any(i == j for i, j in zip(a, b))
False
```

Aplicando el concepto anterior, lo que necesitas es:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
>>> any(i == j for i, j in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]))
True
```

Answer (score -1):

no he usado python, pero por logica lo que haria seria:

```
for int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ { 
      
   if (array[i] != array.lenght) {
        
      if (array[i] == array[i+1]) { son iguales}
   
   }else {
      
      if (array[i] == array[i]) { son iguales}
   
   }

}
```

Comment: Incluso el logica tiene un error. cuando llegues al último elemento de array vas a tener una excepción.